windows resizing when I change to different workspace?
I have 4 workspaces. When I go back to the email workspace from the Chrome workspace, the email window has shrunk, and I need to drag the corner out to get it back to full size. Happens with freecell, and other apps. 22.04.4.

You are using a different workspace for each app? Workspaces are meant to reduce clutter and make the desktop easier to navigate. Workspaces can be used to organize your work. For example, you could have all your communication windows, such as e-mail and your chat program, on one workspace, and the work you are doing on a different workspace. Not really a per app feature. I guess you could use it for that but not the intent.
